# Rails join table with record_type and recored_id like activestorage

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, join

```
create_table :posts do |t|
  t.string   :title
  t.string   :content
end

create_table :post2s do |t|
  t.string   :title
  t.string   :content
end

create_table :users do |t|
  t.string   :email
  t.string   :name
end

create_table :likes do |t|
  t.references :users
  t.string :record_type
  t.integer :record_id
end
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kxBN4.png)

I want to make like join table like Activestorage
with record_type and record_id

Could anyone know this name of join or site to how to create this style of join?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you need a [polymorphic association](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations)

You would therefore have the type and id in your likes table, as you have described. Your models for posts and post2s would identify themselves as being of the polymorphic type.

E.g. posts model: `has_many :likes, as: :likeable` and likes model: `belongs_to :likeable, polymorphic: true`

But do read the guide.

Comment: Thank you so much Matt. This is exactly what I'm looking for.